# Angular 7 - Trouble with angular-ng-autocomplete when trying to build

Tags: angular, angular7, tsconfig, angular-pipe, angular-module

I spent a loft of hours try to build an angular app because I have a trouble with angular-ng-autocomplete.

The problem is with pipe "highlight":

**Template parse errors: The pipe highlight could not be found.**

I tried to fix with some alternatives but not worked: change version for example.

With `ng serve` it is work fine.

With `ng build` too.

But with `ng build --prod` is the problem.

[image: angular 7 angular-ng-autocomplete]

Answer (score 0):

I do not sure how work but in my case I had to turn off `enableIvy` in **tsconfig.json** > `angularCompilerOptions` and it worked.

[image: angular 7 tsconfig enableIvy]